# Creating something like whatsapp voice mail button. Release button don't work

Tags: c#, windows, button, audio, touch-event

I would like to create a function like in Whatsapp for a WPF App with Win10 and with C#. I habe a normal button with some Text on it. As long as the button is pressed with hand touch or a stylus pen, the applikation should record and as soon as the button is untouched, it should stop the recording.

thats my code so far: I may add the I always youse the Preview-Versions of these Events

```
 private void ButtonLiveDown(object sender, touchEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonLiveOn();
    }

 private void ButtonLiveUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {            
        ButtonLiveOff();
    }

    private void ButtonLiveOn()
    {
       SetMicVolume(100);          

        isRecording = true;

       
    }
    
    private void ButtonLiveOff()
    {
        
        SetMicVolume(0);
        
        isRecording = false;

    }
```

for the recording, or better live announcement I use  function in Windows systemsettings where you can say which microphone input schould be sent directly to the speaker
[image: windows setting for live announcement]

Now my Problem: I can start the speaking as soon as I press the button, but it doesn't matter if I hold the button or release him just directly after, The untouch event seems not to work, the Microphone is not set to 0. So I can't stop the live announcement. I want the function like in WhatsApp, the voice message is recording untill the button is released. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you blocking the UI thread by recording so that the release event can't be raised?

Comment: I just change the mic volumne, the rest makes the windows setting which is configured to send everthind directly from the mic to the speaker. I add a screenshot to the question for that

Comment: that way I only need to set the vol of the microphone to 0 when it should stop but the release event is not recognized. even the button itself seem to be pressed when I look at the color

Comment: Hm... but how are you recording? What does your <code>SetMicVolume</code> method (something with UI)? Does the button act as excpeted if you comment out SetMicVolume?

Comment: ok I may have said it not correctly, english isn't my mother language, I don't realy record, I want to make a live announcement. What I say shall be sent directly to the speaker. This is done from windows itself with the settings from the screen shot. All I need to do is setting the volume from the mic to 100% and to stop it to 0% (thats what SetMicVolume is doing only) when the button isn't pressed anymore. but I seem to get not this event that the button isn't pressed anymore